# Why do we ignore the change in kinetic energy of the Earth when applying conservation of energy to the ball-Earth system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, free-fall

Take the ball-Earth system where the ball is being held above the earth a height $h$ from the ground. If we apply conservation of momentum to the system, we can say that
$$ \Delta P = 0 $$
$$ \Delta p_{Earth} + \Delta p_{ball} = 0$$

The momentum of the ball increases in the downward direction and the momentum of the earth cancels it out in the upward direction. Here, we *must* consider the velocity (and momentum) of the Earth, counteracting that of the ball. Indeed, disregarding the change in velocity of the Earth would disastrously result in the idea that $\Delta p_{ball} = 0$, when we know the ball picks up speed as it falls.

However, when applying conservation of energy to the *same ball-Earth system*, we ignore the change in velocity (and kinetic energy) of the Earth, saying:

$$ \Delta K_{ball} + \Delta U_{ball/Earth} = 0 $$

instead of

$$ \Delta K_{ball} + \Delta K_{Earth} + \Delta U_{ball/Earth} = 0 $$

Why would it be safe to ignore $ \Delta K_{Earth} $ above when it is not safe to ignore $ \Delta p_{Earth} $ in the first example?

Comment: Why don't you calculate so me numbers? That will answer you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic energy can be alternatively written as:

$$K=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$

where $p$ is the momentum of the body and $m$ is its mass. Since the momentum of the earth is equal to the momentum of the ball, which is ususally somewhere between $0.1 \text{ Ns}$ to $2 \text{ Ns}$. The earth's mass is somewhere about $6\times 10^{24} \text{ kg}$. Plugging these values in the above equation, we get

$$K_{\text{Earth}}\approx 10^{-25} \text{ J}$$

which is obviously negligible.

Comment: Why did you say that the momentum of earth is equal to the momentum of the ball? I think that is true of the _change_ in momentum of the earth, but not of the momentum itself, right?

Comment: @iRove We are viewing everything from the earth's frame of reference. And thus in this frame, both the momenta will be equal. And we don't have to deal separately with the momentum of the earth in the space frame.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thank you for the explanation!